# Контент начинается под header

Tags: css3, html5

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


/*header*/

header {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #067d7d;
}

#container_content {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 170%;
}

#header-left {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}


/*content*/

#content_inner {
  color: black;
}

#content {}

#content_inner {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content_title {
  font-size: 170%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li,
p {
  font-size: 125%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="container_content">
          <div id="header-left">
            <b>Hay day bot 2020</b>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content_inner">
      <div class="content_title"><b> Why should you choose this bot?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>The fastest hay day bot</li>
        <li>You can change price for selling wheat</li>
        <li>You can change the speed of bot</li>
        <li>The bot works after the latest update</li>
        <li>Bot can grow wheat or corn</li>
        <li>You can change amount of your farms for work bot</li>
        <li>Bot can collect honey</li>
        <li>You will haven't been banned in hay day</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What are your requirements?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Computer/Laptop</li>
        <li>Hay day account(s)</li>
        <li>Programm "Nox"(for bot)</li>
        <li>Programm "TeamViewer" (To manage your pc and install bot)</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How does the bot work?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1 farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will wait for 2 minutes and do it over and over</p>
          </details>

        </li>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1+ farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will switch to the next farm and do it over and over </p>
          </details>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What is price for the bot?</b></div>
      <p>For the present, price is $20 (forever) <br>The price will be increased in the future</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How can you make sure, that i am not a scammer?</b></div>
      <p>If you really want to buy my bot, but you are not sure that i'm not a scammer, just write me and i will send you proofs that i'm not a scammer</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>After you bought the bot, how can you install it?</b></div>
      <p>If you payed me 20$, i will send you a link to download my nox backup. When you finish to download my nox backup, write me and i will connect to your computer by using programm "TeamViewer" and will show you how to start and stop bot
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>Popular questions</b></div>
      <p><b>Q: Can bot work on my mobile phone?</b><br>A: No, because bot needs root,screen resolution (640x480x120) and a lot of settings</p>
      <p><b>Q: What level do i need for the bot</b><br>A: You need farm(s) from 7 lvl and have minimum 10 slots in your shop</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне надо чтобы контент располагался после header и header был фиксированным

---

уже пофиксил, спасибо всем!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Например так

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul,
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

/*header*/

header {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #067d7d;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height: 77px;
}

.header__title {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  margin-top: 85px;
}

#content_inner {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content_title {
  font-size: 170%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li,
p {
  font-size: 125%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__title">Hay day bot 2020</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content_title"><b> Why should you choose this bot?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>The fastest hay day bot</li>
        <li>You can change price for selling wheat</li>
        <li>You can change the speed of bot</li>
        <li>The bot works after the latest update</li>
        <li>Bot can grow wheat or corn</li>
        <li>You can change amount of your farms for work bot</li>
        <li>Bot can collect honey</li>
        <li>You will haven't been banned in hay day</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What are your requirements?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Computer/Laptop</li>
        <li>Hay day account(s)</li>
        <li>Programm "Nox"(for bot)</li>
        <li>Programm "TeamViewer" (To manage your pc and install bot)</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How does the bot work?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1 farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will wait for 2 minutes and do it over and over</p>
          </details>

        </li>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1+ farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will switch to the next farm and do it over and over </p>
          </details>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What is price for the bot?</b></div>
      <p>For the present, price is $20 (forever) <br>The price will be increased in the future</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How can you make sure, that i am not a scammer?</b></div>
      <p>If you really want to buy my bot, but you are not sure that i'm not a scammer, just write me and i will send you proofs that i'm not a scammer</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>After you bought the bot, how can you install it?</b></div>
      <p>If you payed me 20$, i will send you a link to download my nox backup. When you finish to download my nox backup, write me and i will connect to your computer by using programm "TeamViewer" and will show you how to start and stop bot
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>Popular questions</b></div>
      <p><b>Q: Can bot work on my mobile phone?</b><br>A: No, because bot needs root,screen resolution (640x480x120) and a lot of settings</p>
      <p><b>Q: What level do i need for the bot</b><br>A: You need farm(s) from 7 lvl and have minimum 10 slots in your shop</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

А можно вообще не делать блок `fixed`, но он будет как бы fixed

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

:root {
  --height_header: 77px;
  /* высота header */
}

ul,
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}


/*header*/

header {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #067d7d;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height: var(--height_header);
}

.header__title {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  height: calc(100vh - var(--height_header));
  /* 100% высоты экрана минус высота header*/
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#content_inner {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content_title {
  font-size: 170%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li,
p {
  font-size: 125%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__title">Hay day bot 2020</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content_title"><b> Why should you choose this bot?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>The fastest hay day bot</li>
        <li>You can change price for selling wheat</li>
        <li>You can change the speed of bot</li>
        <li>The bot works after the latest update</li>
        <li>Bot can grow wheat or corn</li>
        <li>You can change amount of your farms for work bot</li>
        <li>Bot can collect honey</li>
        <li>You will haven't been banned in hay day</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What are your requirements?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Computer/Laptop</li>
        <li>Hay day account(s)</li>
        <li>Programm "Nox"(for bot)</li>
        <li>Programm "TeamViewer" (To manage your pc and install bot)</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How does the bot work?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1 farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will wait for 2 minutes and do it over and over</p>
          </details>

        </li>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1+ farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will switch to the next farm and do it over and over </p>
          </details>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What is price for the bot?</b></div>
      <p>For the present, price is $20 (forever) <br>The price will be increased in the future</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How can you make sure, that i am not a scammer?</b></div>
      <p>If you really want to buy my bot, but you are not sure that i'm not a scammer, just write me and i will send you proofs that i'm not a scammer</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>After you bought the bot, how can you install it?</b></div>
      <p>If you payed me 20$, i will send you a link to download my nox backup. When you finish to download my nox backup, write me and i will connect to your computer by using programm "TeamViewer" and will show you how to start and stop bot
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>Popular questions</b></div>
      <p><b>Q: Can bot work on my mobile phone?</b><br>A: No, because bot needs root,screen resolution (640x480x120) and a lot of settings</p>
      <p><b>Q: What level do i need for the bot</b><br>A: You need farm(s) from 7 lvl and have minimum 10 slots in your shop</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

А ещё можно с помощью `position: sticky`, тогда вообще не надо знать высоту `header`

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul,
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}


/*header*/

header {
  position: sticky;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #067d7d;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.header__title {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/*content*/

#content_inner {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content_title {
  font-size: 170%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

li,
p {
  font-size: 125%;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__title">Hay day bot 2020</div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content_title"><b> Why should you choose this bot?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>The fastest hay day bot</li>
        <li>You can change price for selling wheat</li>
        <li>You can change the speed of bot</li>
        <li>The bot works after the latest update</li>
        <li>Bot can grow wheat or corn</li>
        <li>You can change amount of your farms for work bot</li>
        <li>Bot can collect honey</li>
        <li>You will haven't been banned in hay day</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What are your requirements?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Computer/Laptop</li>
        <li>Hay day account(s)</li>
        <li>Programm "Nox"(for bot)</li>
        <li>Programm "TeamViewer" (To manage your pc and install bot)</li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How does the bot work?</b></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1 farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will wait for 2 minutes and do it over and over</p>
          </details>

        </li>
        <li>
          <details>
            <summary>1+ farm</summary>
            <p>The Bot will harvest,plant the crop and sell wheat/corn. Then he will switch to the next farm and do it over and over </p>
          </details>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>What is price for the bot?</b></div>
      <p>For the present, price is $20 (forever) <br>The price will be increased in the future</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>How can you make sure, that i am not a scammer?</b></div>
      <p>If you really want to buy my bot, but you are not sure that i'm not a scammer, just write me and i will send you proofs that i'm not a scammer</p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>After you bought the bot, how can you install it?</b></div>
      <p>If you payed me 20$, i will send you a link to download my nox backup. When you finish to download my nox backup, write me and i will connect to your computer by using programm "TeamViewer" and will show you how to start and stop bot
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="content_title"><b>Popular questions</b></div>
      <p><b>Q: Can bot work on my mobile phone?</b><br>A: No, because bot needs root,screen resolution (640x480x120) and a lot of settings</p>
      <p><b>Q: What level do i need for the bot</b><br>A: You need farm(s) from 7 lvl and have minimum 10 slots in your shop</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с `position: sticky;`